# Strange behavior with program sequence

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void delay(int milliseconds) //by http://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=69
{ 
long pause;
clock_t now,then;

pause = milliseconds*(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
now = then = clock();
while( (now-then) < pause )
    now = clock();
}


int main()
{
int i=1;
int j;
while(1)
{
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
    for(j=0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",j);
        if(j==9)
        {
            printf("jump 2");
            i=2;
        }
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    printf("in 2");
    delay(5000);
    printf("jump 1");
    i=1;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

So i streamlined it a bit.

It now should output the numbers 1-9, "jump 2", "in 2" followed by a delay of 5 second and then "jump 1".

In reality it puts out the numbers 1-9, waits 5 seconds and then puts out "jump 2" "in 2" and "jump 1"

Comment: Output buffering, probably. But it's impossible to say for sure because you didn't post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/fflush.html

Comment: Okay, I streamlined my post.

Comment: OK, that confirms it's just buffering.

Comment: Wow... Thanks... A simple \n or fflush(stdout) fixes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just buffering. – melpomene

A simple \n or fflush(stdout) fixes it... – Manuel Burgstaller

Answer (score -1):

This is no 'jump' as you mentioned.
You see the 'break' keyword? That will break the whole switch-case logic.

Check this link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: i guess it looked like I thought its a jump because I didn't do a good post, i just called it jump because it should enter the next case in the next run of the "while(1)" loop around it.